# Thread skips " if " checking statement

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a condition that must occur every 600 millisecond.
I step into thread every 25 millisecond to check if my time amount reached 600 to make the condition happen and then to reset flags and values.

```
    @Override
        public void run() {
            while (runs__) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(25);
                    timeAmount__ = timeAmount__ + delta__;
                    Log.e("process"," " + k++ );
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new  NullPointerException();
                }
                if (delta__ <= 0)
                    timeAmount__ = 0;
                else
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
//                            if (timeAmount__ >= 567 && timeAmount__ < 592) {
                            if (timeAmount__ >= 597 && timeAmount__ < 622) {
                                if (wrongAnswered) {
                                    System.out.println("wrong answered: line 885");
                                    class Ender implements Runnable {
                                        public void run() {
                                            imagesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 2)).setImageDrawable(null);
                                            imagesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 1)).setImageDrawable(null);
                                            imagesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 2)).setBackgroundResource(intAnimationsOff[displayedCharactersIndexesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 2))]);
                                            imagesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 1)).setBackgroundResource(intAnimationsOff[displayedCharactersIndexesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 1))]);
                                            AnimationDrawable animation1 = (AnimationDrawable) imagesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 2)).getBackground();
                                            AnimationDrawable animation2 = (AnimationDrawable) imagesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 1)).getBackground();
                                            animation1.start();
                                            animation2.start();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    soundPool.play(sWrong, sVolume, sVolume, 1, 0, 1);
                                    Ender ender = new Ender();
                                    System.out.println("closing animation: line 900");
                                    imagesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 2)).post(ender);
                                    imagesList.get(lastCells.get(lastCells.size() - 1)).post(ender);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < imagesList.size(); i++)
                                        if (!openedSet.contains(i) && i != clicked)
                                            imagesList.get(i).setEnabled(true);
                                    wrongAnswered = false;
                                    delta = 25;
                                    delta_ = 0;
                                    delta__ = 0;
                                    timeAmount__ = 0;
                                    displayingProcess = false;
                                    choosingProcess = true;
                                    resultProcess = false;
                                    System.out.println("choosing: line 913");
                                } else if (correctAnswered) {
                                    System.out.println("correct answered: line 915");
                                    soundPool.play(sCorrect, sVolume, sVolume, 1, 0, 1);
                                    correctAnswered = false;
                                    if (finishedAll) {
                                        delta = 0;
                                        delta_ = 0;
                                        delta__ = 0;
                                        timeAmount__ = 0;
                                        displayingProcess = false;
                                        choosingProcess = false;
                                        resultProcess = false;
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(PairsGameActivity.this, PairsGameActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("currentLevel", currentLevel);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    } else {
                                        delta = 25;
                                        delta_ = 0;
                                        delta__ = 0;
                                        timeAmount__ = 0;
                                        displayingProcess = false;
                                        choosingProcess = true;
                                        resultProcess = false;
                                        System.out.println("choosing: line 933");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("2. choosingProcess = " + choosingProcess);
                            System.out.println("2. resultProcess = " + resultProcess);
                            System.out.println("2. displayingProcess = " + displayingProcess);
                            System.out.println("2. timeAmount__ process = " + timeAmount__);
                            System.out.println("2. delta__ process = " + delta__);
                        }
                    });
            }
```

and this is the output:

```
         I/System.out: 2. choosingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. resultProcess = true
         I/System.out: 2. displayingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. timeAmount__ process = 525
         I/System.out: 2. delta__ process = 25
         E/process:  871
         I/System.out: 2. choosingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. resultProcess = true
         I/System.out: 2. displayingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. timeAmount__ process = 550
         I/System.out: 2. delta__ process = 25
         E/process:  872
         I/System.out: 2. choosingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. resultProcess = true
         I/System.out: 2. displayingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. timeAmount__ process = 575
         I/System.out: 2. delta__ process = 25
         E/process:  873
         E/process:  874
         I/System.out: 2. choosingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. resultProcess = true
         I/System.out: 2. displayingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. timeAmount__ process = 625
         I/System.out: 2. delta__ process = 25
         I/System.out: 2. choosingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. resultProcess = true
         I/System.out: 2. displayingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. timeAmount__ process = 625
         I/System.out: 2. delta__ process = 25
         E/process:  875
         I/System.out: 2. choosingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. resultProcess = true
         I/System.out: 2. displayingProcess = false
         I/System.out: 2. timeAmount__ process = 650
         I/System.out: 2. delta__ process = 25
```

You can see in outputs the strange behavior.

Instead of entering the `if` loop (assigning 600), the `timeAmount__` assigns value 625 twice after 575 and skips the loop. How I can avoid such behavior?

Comment: Given the double output, it looks more like something is blocking 873 from logging until after 874 starts. If you stored a copy of `timeAmount__` and logged that copy instead, you'd likely see different values.

Comment: Looks like the Runnable started when `timeAmount__` was 600 got delayed in it's execution by 26-74 ms, so `timeAmount__` was updated to 625 and a second Runnable submitted before the first one was executed. Then both ran before the 650 run. Reason: Unknown, but maybe UI thread was busy doing other stuff, or something else was running in the background, slowing things down.

Comment: *Unrelated:* An `if` *statement* is not a *loop*. There is no such thing as an "`if` loop".